# Update value of a variable in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have two files main.py and val.py. A value is taken from val.py in the main file and then I want to update the variable in the original file. Then use that value further in the calculations. Each time when I call the function I want to get the updated value rather than the initial value. But I am only getting the initial value here.

val.py

```
num = 0

#update the original value
def update(num):
  num +=1
  return 

#get the current 'num' value
def current():
  return num
```

Main.py

```
import val

val.update(val.current())

print(val.current())
```

The global variable is not getting updated. I can't seem to figure out the correct issue here. I am passing the values as well in the functions as arguments. It would be really helpful if someone could even give a hint.

Comment: AFAIK, when you do `num +=1`, you're creating a copy of `num`, because integers are immutable: `id(num) => 4511967504; num+=1; id(num) => 4511967536`. I don't think it's possible to _update_ an integer that's passed as argument to another function

Comment: @ForceBru is there any workaround?

Comment: Using `global` as in the answer below is probably the cleanest solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `update()`, you've shadowed the module's `num` variable with a local variable that's also called `num`. If you get rid of it and use the `global` keyword, you can modify the module's `num` value.

```py
num = 0

def update():
    global num
    num += 1
```

Comment: Another query, but why is the ```current()``` returns the correct updated value without the use of global keyword?

Comment: The `global` keyword allows you to modify a variable outside the scope of your function. If you're only reading the variable, you don't need it.